# Strange anamoly in ASP.NET Web Forms (code not working with no errors ...)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm facing a strange anomaly in C# (ASP.NET Web Forms).

I have an ascx Web Page where I call a function creating a JSON from localStorage values.

```
function creerJsonDepuisLocalStorage() {
        var modif = {}

        // Filling modif with localStorage values ...         

        try {
            return JSON.stringify(modifs);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return "";
        }

    }
```

My codebehind is called on submit button click and recover the JSON to use it.

```
protected void btnEnregistrerFiche_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // tons of code ... doing various things like !!DataBase access!!

    string argument = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; 
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    try
    {
        FicheModifiee edits = ser.Deserialize<FicheModifiee>(argument);
        // edits treatments, commented for debug
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    // some other code like !!UI update!!
}
```

My problem is the following :

When my front end javascript function returns an empty string, the codebehind function works like a charm, doing database modifications and updating UI.

When my front end javascript function returns a real object, the codebehind function is correctly deserializing the JSON into the edits class and I don't have any bug or crashes **BUT** database access isn't made and UI is updating with previous data (not considering any changes made before submitting).

This sounds like dark magic as I'm not getting any crashes and my little piece of code isn't doing anything with the rest of the function ...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you attach a debugger and step through the code?

Comment: Yes I did, but the rest of the code isn't mine and calling a lot of other functions. For now I can say that every functions before and after my bloc isn't crashing and returning correct values.

Comment: @Jasone.L what is the data u are getting in ur object

Comment: @Webruster A simple data object created in the javascript, containing mostly strings and some DateTimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by using an asp:hiddentField (set at the end of my json creation script) and by reading it directly from C# code. Still not knowing what happend with `Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];`